# Dispatch action from child with payload (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following piece of code in my chid component

```
export const PayPalSecureMessage = (props: TProps) => {
  let ecValue = { ecToken: "", paymentDetails: {} };

  const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

  const createOrder = async (data, actions) => {
      ecValue = await getECToken(
        props.orderTotal,
        true
      );
      return ecValue.ecToken;
  };


  return (
          <div>
          <PayPalButton
              env="sandbox"
              createOrder={createOrder}
          />
          </div>
  )

};
```

And this is the container code

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  isSummaryFailed: getPaymentsFailure,
  orderTotal: getOrderTotal,
  hasSubscription: getSubscriptionItemPresence
});
```

As you can see, i have mapStateToProps so that anything in the parent component change, i will be able to update my child component due to this mapping above.

Now, i want to dispatch an action from child component. `createOrder` that you see above is actually called on button click. but i need to pass payload data along with this action call.

So something like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  createOrder: callCreateOrder(payload), //how to pass payload with action dispatcher here?
  removeCard: removeGiftCard
};
```

Can someone please shed some light as to how do i dispatch an action along with the payload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `dispatch` in your `mapDispatchToProps` or anywhere in your code provided.

Your `mapDispatchToProps` should be something like (according to the docs) :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: 'RESET' })
  }
}
```

which you sent the payload by doing

```
increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT', payload: whateverNumYouWantToIncre })
```

or if you define `mapDispatchToProps` like this then your payload can directly put inside the bracket of your dispatched action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  toggleTodo: () => dispatch(toggleTodo(ownProps.todoId))
}
```

You may want to take a look at the official document of redux [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)